# PHPMailer connect SMTP server success, but Could not authenticate

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

i use PHPMailer in my project to send Email, and my code works fine in local, but got error in live server.

i have checked the port in live server with below code and it works fine:

```
telnet smtp.partner.outlook.cn 587
```

here is the PHP code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                      
$mail->isSMTP();                       

$mail->Host       = 'smtp.partner.outlook.cn';                   
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
$mail->Username   = 'xxx';             
$mail->Password   = 'xxx';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('xxx', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('xxxx', 'Me');    


//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                 
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
```

below is the error log：

```
2023-02-28 09:46:41 Connection: opening to         smtp.partner.outlook.cn:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2023-02-28 09:46:41 Connection: opened
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "220 SHXPR01CAXX.partner.outlook.cn Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 28 Feb 2023 09:46:43 +0000"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220     SHXPR01CAXX.partner.outlook.cn Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at     Tue, 28 Feb 2023 09:46:43 +0000
2023-02-28 09:46:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mysite.com
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SHXPR01CAXX.partner.outlook.cn Hello [180.167.224.181]"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-    SHXPR01CAXX.partner.outlook.cn Hello [180.167.224.181]250-SIZE     157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-    8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2023-02-28 09:46:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2023-02-28 09:46:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2023-02-28 09:46:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mysite.com
2023-02-28 09:51:41 SMTP -> get_lines(): select timed-out in (300 sec)
2023-02-28 09:51:41 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2023-02-28 09:51:41 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2023-02-28 09:51:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO mysite.com
2023-02-28 09:51:41 SMTP INBOUND: ""
2023-02-28 09:51:41 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2023-02-28 09:51:41 SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed:
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2023-02-28 09:51:41 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if     connected
2023-02-28 09:51:41 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not     authenticate.SMTP server error: Called QUIT without being connected
```

I have google it for several days， but didn't find any info around this. Port and username and  password are all correct.

can anyone help me with this or give me some advice

I want to send email in phpmailer.

Comment: I believe outlook (like Gmail) requires you to create an App Password and possibly do some other security stuff before you can connect to it from an external service (such as your PHP application). Consult your settings and their documentation in case that's something you need to do.

Comment: P.S. As per [ask] please don't provide pictures of data such as error logs. There's no reason you can't provide it as text, then it's easier to read, searchable, and we can copy/search things from it. See also [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your reply , the code works fine in the local , so i think  it is not related to the outlook server. and the reason i post a pic is because the stackoverflow consider the log text as spam,and don't let me post the question.

Comment: "spam"? Really? What exact message did it give you? Did you format it as either code or a quotation? That should allow it to be accepted.

Comment: Anyway, it seems to be failing on the EHLO/HELO command where your server tells Outlook who it is. Possibly Outlook doesn't permit connections from your domain.

Comment: i think i made a wrong format . thanks for the advice

Comment: I think the most likely explanation (since it's hanging on enabling TLS) is that certificate verification is failing because the CA certificates in your server are out of date. There's lots of [info on that subject in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure). It should at least be giving you decent error messages, so it's a little odd that it's just hanging. Perhaps try `ssl` mode on port 465? Azure and Outlook's XOAUTH2 authentication is proving troublesome for many people, far more so than Google's.